# iTextSharp: Put blank space before a table

Tags: c#, itext

I'm using iTextSharp to render an html page in a PDF file.

Rendering is ok but i can't find a way to put some blank space before every table.

Now the text before the table is too close.

Is there an attribute I can add to the stylesheet?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Are you using iTextSharp's XMLWorker?  In that case, the CSS property "margin-top" should help you.

If you're referring to HTMLWorker: it is deprecated in favor of XMLWorker, so you may consider migrating.